# Does Tridion use cookies to store login information of a Trustee?

Tags: cme, 2013

Mexico law doesn't allow cookie based authorization.So i would like to know whether Tridion 2013 Sp1 uses any cookies to store login information.

Found no cookies when executed a cookie checker on CM Explorer.

Previously i think R5 used to have cookies enabled.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Content Manager and XPM both use Windows (NTLM) Authentication. Regarding authorisation, the signed-in user name is passed in Post headers, and the group memberships are determined and handled all server side without the need for a cookie.

Comment: Indeed. And this has always been the case, even in R5. I want to note that there is an optional cookie set, but it doesn't contain login information (only language/locale settings) and the CME works fine without cookies enabled.